# Changing values on one dataframe based on data in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames as follows:

```
test1 <- structure(list(`0.62m` = c(0.011, 0.043, 0.057, 0.067, 0.095, 
0.121, 0.098, 0.086, 0.103, 0.12, 0.104), `0.87m` = c(0.017, 
0.018, 0.052, 0.062, 0.111, 0.101, 0.112, 0.096, 0.104, 0.108, 
0.111), `1.12m` = c(0.009, 0.016, 0.048, 0.03, 0.085, 0.07, 0.108, 
0.076, 0.078, 0.092, 0.107), `1.37m` = c(0.025, 0.035, 0.035, 
0.048, 0.067, 0.074, 0.095, 0.08, 0.082, 0.091, 0.094)), .Names = c("0.62m", 
"0.87m", "1.12m", "1.37m"), row.names = 25:35, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

#Test 2
test2 <- structure(list(`0.62m` = c(235.15, 230.95, 251.95, 261.25, 254.55, 
251.75, 259.85, 257.65, 252.55, 255.55, 254.15), `0.87m` = c(287.95, 
196.35, 275.05, 245.85, 253.35, 259.75, 254.95, 261.75, 253.05, 
264.45, 264.25), `1.12m` = c(36.35, 242.95, 266.65, 266.45, 248.85, 
256.95, 253.75, 268.25, 251.05, 268.85, 259.65), `1.37m` = c(20.65, 
287.95, 260.25, 260.55, 255.25, 258.45, 248.45, 261.95, 253.45, 
263.25, 252.05)), .Names = c("0.62m", "0.87m", "1.12m", "1.37m"
), row.names = 25:35, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Test 1 looks like following:

```
   0.62m 0.87m 1.12m 1.37m
25 0.011 0.017 0.009 0.025
26 0.043 0.018 0.016 0.035
27 0.057 0.052 0.048 0.035
28 0.067 0.062 0.030 0.048
29 0.095 0.111 0.085 0.067
30 0.121 0.101 0.070 0.074
31 0.098 0.112 0.108 0.095
32 0.086 0.096 0.076 0.080
33 0.103 0.104 0.078 0.082
34 0.120 0.108 0.092 0.091
35 0.104 0.111 0.107 0.094
```

Test 2 looks like following:

```
    0.62m  0.87m  1.12m  1.37m
25 235.15 287.95  36.35  20.65
26 230.95 196.35 242.95 287.95
27 251.95 275.05 266.65 260.25
28 261.25 245.85 266.45 260.55
29 254.55 253.35 248.85 255.25
30 251.75 259.75 256.95 258.45
31 259.85 254.95 253.75 248.45
32 257.65 261.75 268.25 261.95
33 252.55 253.05 251.05 253.45
34 255.55 264.45 268.85 263.25
35 254.15 264.25 259.65 252.05
```

Now, I want to create a new dataframe test3 where I need to check if values in test2 is greater than 180 or not. If the value is greater than 180, then the elements should be same as test1 else it should be -1 * test1.

**The desired ouput would look like following:**

```
    0.62m 0.87m 1.12m 1.37m
25 0.011 0.017 -0.009 -0.025
26 0.043 0.018 0.016 0.035
```

I tried following:

```
test3 <- ifelse(test2 > 180, test1, -1 * test1)
```

Another method:

```
test3 <- data.frame(sapply(X = test1, FUN = function(x) (ifelse(test2>180, x, - 1*x))))
```

I think I need to use apply but not sure how to use that properly.

Comment: I think your first approach should work once you convert your data sets into matrices.

Answer (score 4):

You just need some `as.matrix()` calls (note that only the two rightmost cells in the top row are actually less than 180):

```
ifelse(as.matrix(test2)>180,as.matrix(test1),-as.matrix(test1));
##    0.62m 0.87m  1.12m  1.37m
## 25 0.011 0.017 -0.009 -0.025
## 26 0.043 0.018  0.016  0.035
## 27 0.057 0.052  0.048  0.035
## 28 0.067 0.062  0.030  0.048
## 29 0.095 0.111  0.085  0.067
## 30 0.121 0.101  0.070  0.074
## 31 0.098 0.112  0.108  0.095
## 32 0.086 0.096  0.076  0.080
## 33 0.103 0.104  0.078  0.082
## 34 0.120 0.108  0.092  0.091
## 35 0.104 0.111  0.107  0.094
```

The return value will be a matrix, but you can get back to a data.frame (if you want) via `as.data.frame()`.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Your approach is more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
 test1*((test2<=180) *-1+ (test2>180))
 #    0.62m 0.87m  1.12m  1.37m
 #25 0.011 0.017 -0.009 -0.025
 #26 0.043 0.018  0.016  0.035
 #27 0.057 0.052  0.048  0.035
 #28 0.067 0.062  0.030  0.048
 #29 0.095 0.111  0.085  0.067
 #30 0.121 0.101  0.070  0.074
 #31 0.098 0.112  0.108  0.095
 #32 0.086 0.096  0.076  0.080
 #33 0.103 0.104  0.078  0.082
 #34 0.120 0.108  0.092  0.091
 #35 0.104 0.111  0.107  0.094
```

Or a more elegant option suggested by @Marat Talipov (in the comments)

```
 test1*((test2>180)*2-1)
```

Comment: or `test1*((test2>180)*2-1)`

Comment: @bgoldst Thanks, I was first trying to post `as.matrix`, but then I saw the comment of MaratTalipov.  Yours is also good

Comment: +1 Thanks akrun. Didn't know we could use something like this. One can learn a lot through alternate answers.

Comment: @MaratTalipov Thanks, it is more elegant. I was trying to use `sign` function, but couldn't get it right

Comment: Just for fun, I ran some bench with the 3 solutions. The saved logical check saves 13% computation time for me...haha. Though I don't know what kind of magic `ifelse()` is pulling because that solution demolishes (50% time) these two even with the `as.matrix` conversion.

Comment: @Akrun `g = function(z) ifelse(as.matrix(test2)>180,as.matrix(test1),-as.matrix(test1));f = function(z) test1*((test2<=180) *-1+ (test2>180));k = function(z) test1*((test2>180)*2-1);l = function(z) {indx <- test2 <= 180; test1[indx] <- -test1[indx]};microbenchmark(g(), f(), k(), l(), times = 100L)`

Comment: @Vlo the question usually is what's the size of your data. There is no real value in benchmarking 35 row data set really

Comment: @David Arenburg That is a good point. I was just benching for this problem. With `test1=test2=matrix(rnorm(100000))` and `180` changed to `0`, `k()` is the best solution. Relative order stays the same when n is changed to 1e6. I'm trying to understand how the overhead for `ifelse` is so low.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I tried with 2000*2000 dataset, and your solution is faster wrt to mine on system.time

Answer (score 4):

Another solution could be (the desired result will be stored in `test1`)

```
indx <- test2 <= 180
test1[indx] <- -test1[indx]
```

Comment: Another brilliant solution.